# Keeping an open connection in Internet Explorer (7,8,9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, iis-7

I am in a project where I need to connect to a client's server and retrieve data for some graphs.

The client wants this to be something in real time (they have a script that is listening for connections and feeds data constantly).

My big problem is that I don't think this can be done in IE as easy as it would be done in Firefox or Chrome. Firefox and Chrome both support web sockets so I think I could make something that would do exactly what the client wants.

In IE the only way I could do this is by using a setTimeout with an ajax call.

Is there any other alternative for IE??

For now we're using jquery .ajax() and setting a callback for the onReadystageChanged event that handles the server response when the readyState == 3. But this doesn't work as expected because the connection closes after the first response.

Also, I am using IIS with Application Request Routing module as a proxy and a URL rewriting rule because we're using cross domain services. But this module uses a buffer with at least 1KB that corrupts the server response. The services were created by another company that won't implement CORS specification in their server.

How can I work around this and receive the response without buffering?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WebSockets you can use long polling and a server side promise.

On the server you can suspend the http request so it works async.

**Example jQuery**:

```
poll();    
function poll(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://my-own-domain.com/data/",
        success : function(data) {
            //do what you want with data
            poll();
        },
        error : function(data) {
            poll();
        }
    });
}
```

**Server side example:**

```
WSRequest req = WS.url("http://the-other-domain.org/data/");
Promise<HttpResponse> respAsync = req.getAsync();
HttpResponse resp = await(respAsync);
renderJSON(resp.getString());
```

For server side take a look at [Play! Framework Async](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/asynchronous) to get an idea how it can be done.